# Is it "Hover over the icon to learn more about A book's content" OR "Hover over the icon to learn more about THE book's content"?

Tags: grammar, articles, construction

I'm writing some 'help' content for a website, and I've been stumped by an article.

There are several books, so there are several icons onscreen at any one time. When you hover over a book's icon, you get a short summary of the book.

What would be correct to say in this case?

> Hover over the icon to learn more about **a** book's content.

Or

> Hover over the icon to learn more about **the** book's content.

Or could it be something else? I've been told by the higher-ups to avoid a "Hover over each book's icon" construction, unfortunately.

Comment: How about "Hover over _an_ icon (any one of several) to learn more about _the_ book's content (the book which the chosen icon relates to)"?

Comment: @KateBunting "An"! I didn't even think about replacing the first article in the sentence. I think that should work actually. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: You've run into one of the many third rails of technical writing. Get ready for users sarcastically commenting that they aren't able to hover over such a small space, because they aren't able to levitate.

Comment: @FeliniusRex I know comments are for clarification and all that, but I just had to say that you gave me a good laugh.